# onchange - the dropdown selected using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a dropdown in the header and whatever the value is selected in the header should reflect the same in the detail dropdown, how should i do that? any leads?

```
$("#myddl").change(function()
{ 
     //update all the dropdown list...  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/4QvfP/

```
  Header:
    <br />
    <select id="myddl" name="myddl">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Twooo</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <p>Detail</p>
        <br />
    <select id="Select1" name="myddl">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Twooo</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <select id="Select2" name="myddl">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Twooo</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <select id="Select3" name="myddl">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Twooo</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <select id="Select4" name="myddl">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Twooo</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <select id="Select5" name="myddl">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Twooo</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: thank you all, let me try and get back to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along these lines will work. It wraps your "Detail" selects in a container to make selection somewhat simpler.

http://jsfiddle.net/qMXSR/2/

```
$("#myddl").change(function()
{ 
     $('.detail').find('select').val($(this).val());
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$.on` to bind to the "change" event. From here we target all `select` elements whose `id` begins with `Select` - which includes all of those below. Then we set their value(s) to that of the current one.

```
​$("#myddl").on("change", function(o){
   $("select[id^=Select]").val(o.target.value);
});​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: $("select[id^=Select]").val(o.target.value) 'o' is undefined Error

Comment: @AbuHamzah That's odd. The code works *as-is*: http://jsbin.com/ituviq/edit#javascript,html Which Browser/Version/Version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This code will do it:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#myddl").live('change', function()
    {
        $("#Select1, #Select2, #Select3, #Select4, #Select5").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

The updated JS Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/4QvfP/7/

Answer (score 1):

```
​$(function(){
    $('#myddl').change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $('select[name=myddl] option[value='+value+']').attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
})​
```

Comment: doest really change the detail dropdown

Comment: 1+ thanks i have post another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501286/jquery-select-all-checkbox-only-if-its-not-selected

Answer (score 0):

In the onchange of the first dropdown, you can jQuery select the other dropdowns and use a .each() to iterate and set the other options.