# jQuery select all checkbox only if its not selected

Tags: jquery

How can I make sure the user select the checkbox should only be approve or reject all not both? and let says if the user select two `approve` (for an example) and click on `reject all` then it should only be checked two in the `reject column` since two checkbox is already checked in the 'approve column'

Here is what i attempt and not complet but you will get an idea of what i am trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/CgqVw/6/

Comment: Do you mean that the number of approve should be equal to the number of reject?

Comment: Should the user be able to both approve and reject something at the same time? That is what your sample implies.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are looking for, but I gave it a try. Let me know if I missed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? Note I changed your html a little to make the process a little easier.

**HTML**:

```
<table class="style1" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Approve All<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="approve" />
        </td>
        <td>
            Reject All<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="reject" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="employee" class="approve" />
            <span>John</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="employer" class="reject" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="employee0" class="approve" />
            <span>John</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="employer" class="reject" />
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="employee1" class="approve" />
            <span>John</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="employer" class="reject" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="employee" class="approve" />
            <span>John</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="employer" class="reject" />
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

​

**Javascript**:

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name=approve]').click(function(){
        var checked = this.checked;

        $('.approve').each(function() {
            if($(this).closest('tr').find('.reject').prop('checked') == false)
                this.checked = checked;
        });
    });          

    $('input[name=reject]').click(function(){
        var checked = this.checked;

        $('.reject').each(function() {
            if($(this).closest('tr').find('.approve').prop('checked') == false)
                this.checked = checked;
        });
    });

    $('.approve').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.reject').prop('checked', !this.checked);
    });

     $('.reject').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.approve').prop('checked', !this.checked);
    });
});​
```

**[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CgqVw/15/)**

Comment: thanks Josh i am testing now and yes thats what i was looking for. 1+

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure do you need something like this?

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name=approve]').click(function(){
        $('.style6 input').attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });          

    $('input[name=reject]').click(function(){
        $('.style5 input').attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });        
});​
```

And [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3E28n/2/)

Comment: not exactly, i have updated the fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/abuhamzah/CgqVw/6/

hopefully this will be clear when you look at the fiddler, i am trying to select checkbox either approve or reject and can not be select both in this case (approve and reject)

Comment: hmmm i think its very close... so right now i can either select approve or reject which is fine but here is one condition... if i select approve all and un-check say second and third checkbox from the approve column and then i check on reject all and once i click on reject all, i want first and fourth to be selected since i have already select second and third in the approve column.... make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use radio buttons instead of checkboxes.  Radio buttons come pre-built with this kind of 'select one' functionality, and are better from a UI design perspective.  And also the approve/reject all boxes should probably be buttons.

When you click the approve/reject all, you could iterate through the radio groups that have been checked so far and make the appropriate adjustments.  Something like this will grab those:

```
$('input:radio[name=bar]:checked')
```

Comment: i understand what you are trying to say but in my situation i have to use checkbox